# Prevent IntelliJ from executing Maven plugins in parallel to compilation

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I've just setup a Maven-based Spring Boot project in IntelliJ (without delegating commands to Maven itself) containing jOOQ and Flyway that I intend to run before every build. Running `mvn compile` via the command line yields the correct behavior since both plugins do register themselves to the correct lifecycle phase.

However when setting the `Before Build` trigger in IntelliJ like this I end up with an unexpected behavior:

[image]

When invoking the build process via the menu or the menubar button both the compiler and the code generation are started and running in parallel. The result is that the compiler throws errors that are automatically resolved just moments later. The compilation inside of IntelliJ does not wait for the Maven process to finish in the first place.

Is there any option to make IntelliJ's build process aware of the Maven progress?

Comment: Not certain, but you might have some success with setting *Build Exection Deployment > Build Tools > Maven > Runner > Delegate IDE Build/run actions to Maven* to true. Try disabling "*run in background*" too, same dialog.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this should work, but in doing so I am forfeiting some caching that IntelliJ provides during build. I am curious whether this behavior is a bug was always like that since it doesn't make sense to run code generation in parallel to compilation.

Comment: @Michael I just checked - it works as expected. However as mentioned I am losing out on optimization and caching from IntelliJs compilation process as well as responsiveness. Clicking on the build command does not show any output or progress indicator even with the option *Run in background* disabled.

Comment: The only compromise is to run the `compile` lifecycle from within the Maven window - however when invoking a debug session IntelliJ compiles the files for a second time.

Comment: Does your build work on plain command line?

Comment: @khmarbaise It does. It's just the fact that IntelliJ runs the codegen via Maven and the compiler internally simultaneously.

Comment: To which build phases is  codegen bound to? Apart from that. This sounds like the plugins are not configured correctly ...?

Comment: @khmarbaise They are bound to the `generate-sources` phase. But it seems this doesn't affect the way the code is compiled since IntelliJ isn't triggering the compilation via Maven in the first place and thus there is no dependency between the tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-230004).

Please try the [EAP version](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/).

Comment: I just tried out the 2020.1 Beta and it behaves correct, so it was a bug after all. Thanks for the quick first-party help :)